# Get the input path in a Hadoop Mapper Class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have implemented a simple MapReduce project in [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) for processing logs. The input path is the directory where the logs are.

It works fine but I would like to know how the input path of the log is being processed at any time in the class which implements the Mapper. The Mapper code is:

```
public class StatsMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<WritableComparable<Text>,Text,Text,Text> { 

    public static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(StatsMapper.class);

    public void configure(JobConf conf) {}

    public void map(WritableComparable<Text> key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        process(key,value);

    }

}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What means 'how the input path of the log is being processed'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the InputFormat section [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#inputformat)

> How these input files are split up and read is defined by the InputFormat. An InputFormat is a class that provides the following functionality:
>   Selects the files or other objects that should be used for input
>   Defines the InputSplits that break a file into tasks
>   Provides a factory for RecordReader objects that read the file